# “Fixed the crashing issue that occured when... was saved...” vs. “Fixed the the crashing issue that occurs when... is saved..”

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

In the case outlined above where the issue has already been fixed, hence it no longer is an issue, what is the correct verb tense for the ‘that’ clause that describes the issue itself?? I personally thought it should remain as present as it was an issue that occurs everytime in that specific situation, regardless of whether it was fixed or is being fixed. My coworker said it should all be past tense because the issue has been fixed therefor the description of the issue no longer describes a valid issue, as it has been fixed. Please... help... now i am just confusing myself

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of house style. Some companies prefer to write release notes that refer to the problem from the perspective of the version it occurred in (in the present tense), and others prefer to write them from the perspective of the new version (i.e. the problem no longer exists, so we'll write about it in the past tense).

However, it seems a bit awkward to use the present tense after the past tense "fixed", so I'd suggest that if you want to use present tense, you also use "Fixes". So, either of these would be fine:

- Fixes an issue that occurs when...
- Fixed an issue that occurs when...

Note that there's a difference in the assumed subject of these sentences. For "Fixes", the subject is arguably the update version, i.e. "Version 2.0 fixes an issue that occurs when...". For "fixed", the subject could be the company/developers, e.g. "HighTech inc has fixed...", or "We have fixed..."

For that reason, if you're writing these release notes as a note to other developers on your team, and you want to write as though you yourself being the subject (i.e. "I have fixed..."), "fixes" would not be correct ("I fixes" is ungrammatical).

Some companies will even simply write the bug descriptions themselves (in present tense) under a fix list. For example, see: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2018-06/

Any of the above options could be considered correct, but it depends on the perspective of your release notes, and the house style. Whichever you choose, you should be consistent every time you write the release notes.

On a separate matter, "crashing issue" isn't very good technical writing! It would be better to write "Fixed an issue that caused the computer to crash when...", or "Fixed a crash that occurred when..."